# Angular D3 tdd, test svg created

Tags: angular, tdd

I have a stackblitz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-graph-tooltip?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbar-chart.ts

It's a simple D3 chart in Angular.

I'm trying to write a unit test to see if the svg is created.

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { FirstVLastGraphComponent } from './first-v-last-graph.component';
import {NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA} from "@angular/core";

describe('FirstVLastGraphComponent', () => {
  let component: FirstVLastGraphComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FirstVLastGraphComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ FirstVLastGraphComponent ],
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FirstVLastGraphComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
      component.data = [];
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should render an svg', ()=>{
        const svgCon = component.initSvg();
        expect(svgCon).toContain( );
  });


});
```

Can I test if an html element is creaeted in the 'toContain()'

Comment: You need to use the component's native element and query if it contains a child SVG element. You have to use the browser DOM APIs because D3 does not support Angular's renderer service.